# WCF Notify subscribers asynchronously

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

This is my WCF service. I want to notify multiple subscribers of 
some updates and do it asynchronously. How do I do that?

```
// Callback contract
public interface IMyServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Notify(String sData);      
}

public class MyService:IMyService
{
    List<IMyServiceCallback> _subscribers = new List<IMyServiceCallback>();

    // This function is used to subscribe to service.
    public bool Subscribe()
    {
       try
       {
          IMyServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallback>();
        if (!_subscribers.Contains(callback))
            _subscribers.Add(callback);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// this function is used to notify all the subsribers 
// I want ForEach to be asynchronous. 
public void OnGetMsg(string sData)
{
    _subscribers.ForEach(
            callback =>
            {
                if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                    callback.Notify(sData); //THIS OPERATION
                }
                else
                {
                    _subscribers.Remove(callback);
                }
            });
   }
}
```

- ["MSDN: WCF Publisher/Subscriber Client crashing" is strongly related to my problem.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5cfb384d-291a-49c1-b089-0cafde59a5d5)
- I have followed [Mini Webcast](http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/) while creating this service.

Comment: Also, am I the only one who thinks WCF is pain in the neck? (You know what I mean by neck.)

Comment: Where is your problem in the code? Exception or logic (algo) problem?

Comment: If one of the subscribers is dead then there is Timeout Exception at  `callback.Notify()`. Because of this notification to other subscribers is delayed.

Comment: If you dont handle that TimeoutException inside that method, the ForEach will break, something like waiting for the other process to complete.  Are you handling the exception inside the callback.Notify method()?

Comment: I can handle that `TimeoutException` but it won't prevent the delayed notification to other subscribers.

Comment: Have you limit your connection timeout? How many seconds will that cause a delay if you have 3 seconds connection timeout?  When you handle the exception, does the code still crashed?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it to the thread pool:

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => callback.Notify(sData));
```

Just be aware that it might clog up your threadpool when you have many bad subscribers. You probably want to catch exceptions and remove the callback when it failed.

**Update**: If you don't want to use the .NET thread pool then you can either roll your own or for example use the [SmartThreadPool](http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That is not a good idea because you will most probably consume threads which are supposed to be used by WCF engine to process incomming requests.